# Syncthing does not work with AFwall+ activated

Tags: sync, connection-issues, lineageos, firewall

Syncthing does not get any connection as long as AFwall+ is activated.
It should work in my WLAN at home. Mobile data is disabled because I don't need it.
I am using LineageOS on my mobile phone.

Here are my settings of AFwall+ (I only allow wireless communication for Syncthing)
[image: Only WLAN activated]

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to disable wireless (WLAN) in AFwall+ and activate LAN.
This does not make sense for me, but it works...
It still works if I activate wireless as well, but it is not necessary.

[image: Activate LAN]

Even if I disable wireless access within AFwall+ I still need to be connected to a WLAN within Android (what makes at least some sense).